# How to properly display the the Chinese information coming in the http header?

Tags: python, html, header, codec

For example, after a Get request, the Server returns the following information:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Mon, 19 Jan 2009 06:37:47 GMT 
Server: IBM_HTTP_Server/6.0.2 Apache/2.0.47 (Unix) 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MPLS TE Switching%E6%96%B9%E6%A1%88%E7%99%BD%E7%9A%AE%E4%B9%A6.pdf 
Content-Length: 1444670 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream 
Content-Language: zh-CN
```

MPLS TE Switching%E6%96%B9%E6%A1%88%E7%99%BD%E7%9A%AE%E4%B9%A6.pdf is a Chinese string filename, it should be how to convert to display properly?
what i have done is to use:

```
filename.decode("iso-8859-1")
```

but it didn't work!

Comment: ISO-8859 is great for European languages, for Asian languages it's a bit small.

Comment: yes,when i change to gbk,it works!thanks